# Delete function in view | Laravel

Tags: laravel

I have this function to delete only a row from a table in my database.

```
public function delete($id)
{
DB::table('user')->where('userID', '=', $id)->delete();
return redirect('userAdmin');
}
```

And I have a button which gets created for every row.

```html
@foreach ($scores as $score)
<tr>
    <td>{{ $score->id }}</td>
    <td>{{ $score->serialnumber }}</td>
    <td>{{ $score->name }}</td>
    <td>{{ $score->created_at }}</td>
    <td></td>
    <td>
        <button class="btn btn-danger" type="submit">Delete this Row</button>
        {{ csrf_field() }}
    </td>
</tr>
```

How do I get a delete functionality behind it?

Answer (score 1):

In your view:

```
<form action="{{ route('yourmodel.delete', $score->id) }}" method="post">
    {{ csrf_field() }}
    <input name="_method" type="hidden" value="DELETE">
    <button class="btn btn-danger" type="submit">Delete</button>
</form>
```

Add a route with a name you like, and a parameter for the id. Let that route call the method in your example and you should be good.

There isn't really such a thing as a `DELETE` function in HTML forms, so you have to spoof it. Take a look at the [docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/routing#form-method-spoofing).

Comment: I have tried something like this: Route::get('Test/{id}', 'TestController@delete')->name('mymodel.delete'); but i get a route not defined..

Comment: When i press the delete button now its just pastin the user input to the url... http://localhost:204/Test1/Test2/Test200000000 like this. Whis is this?

Comment: You can't send delete requests to a get route. `Route::delete('test/{id}', ` etc etc.

Comment: I came a bit further i think the route is working for now but i get this weird error message that i never have seen while coding with laravel: Type error: Too few arguments to function App\Http\Controllers\TestDevicesController::delete(), 0 passed and exactly 1 expected

Comment: Sounds like you're not actually sending the ID along from your form. Check if you do :)

Comment: Ok now i have got no message. Does that mean he just paste nothing or what... im really a beginner and try my best ....

Answer (score -1):

In your view:

```
<form action="{{ route('yourmodel.delete', $score->id) }}" method="post">
 {{ csrf_field() }}
   @foreach ($scores as $score)
   <tr>
     <td>{{ $score->id }}</td>
     <td>{{ $score->serialnumber }}</td>
     <td>{{ $score->name }}</td>
     <td>{{ $score->created_at }}</td>
     <td></td>
   <td>
  <button class="btn btn-danger" type="submit">Delete this Row</button>
 </td>
@endforeach


</form>
```

In your routes:

```
 Route::post('Test/{id}', 'TestController@delete')->name('yourmodel.delete');
```

Comment: So you've basically copied my answer with a route that should fail?

Comment: Then why add the hidden delete method?